# Create a query in Microsoft Access 2013 that displays current status

Tags: sql, database, ms-access-2013

I am trying to create a query in Access 2013 that shows the current status and date, while ignoring older status records.

I have three tables:

customer
     id (pk)
     last
     first

status
     id (pk)
     status
     description

status-customer
     id (pk)
     customer_id
     status_id
     status_date
     notes

If I create a query with the fields last, first, customer_id, and status_date, where it is grouped on last status_date, it works great.  But I can't get the query to list the current status based on the status_date.  No matter how I add the status, it breaks the grouping and shows the same person with multiple statuses.

For example:

```
Last        First        Customer_id         Status_date
John         Smith              1               05/30/2015
Mary         Johnson            2               05/26/2015



Last        First        Customer_id         Status_date       Status
John         Smith              1               05/25/2015       In Process
John         Smith              1               05/30/2015       Complete
Mary         Johnson            2               05/26/2015       Complete
```

I want something like the second query, but without the duplicated records.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I uploaded my solution: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ef4b9/1/0

```
SELECT c.first,c.last,c.id as customer_id,sc.status_date,s.name
FROM customer c 
left join customer_status sc on sc.customer_id=c.id
left join status s on s.id=sc.status_id
where sc.id=(SELECT MAX(id) from 
             customer_status WHERE customer_id=sc.customer_id)
```

Comment: I've taken the last id on customer_Status and not the last date because if there are multiple status update on same date we want the last inserted status.
This is the sql server 2014 syntax should be the same in access...

Comment: I think I is close, and I don't see any errors in the sql, but Access consistently returns the following message:  Syntex error (missing operator) in query expression 'sc.customer_id=c.id left join status s n s.id=sc.status_i'

Comment: post the query that you are trying to execute